# Как определить класс с интерфейсом так, что бы он имел методы интерфейса, но без их реализации

Tags: c#, .net, generics, c#-7.0, .net-4.8

Что я имел ввиду в заголовке, так это то, что бы к примеру абстрактный класс, мог стать контейнером некого интерфейса, и что бы при обращении к этому классу, я имел доступ ко всем методам интерфейса, но так что бы мне не приходилось их реализовывать вручную.

Я где-то видел такое решение. но вспомнить не могу. Там на дженериках все было завязано, `in, out` как параметр типа, вроде бы имьютейбл или что то такое.

> Уточнение:
>   Есть интерфейс, который не нужно реализовывать, но нужен класс контейнер, черзе который можно работать с этим интерфейсом, без геттеров и тому прочей ерунды, но не реализовывать методы в классе.

> Уточнение №2: **что то на подобии перегрузки оператора -> в `C++`**, т.е. в `C++` можно поместить указатель на структуру/класс, и перегрузив оператор `->` должным образом, работать с указателем на некий класс, а не с тем классом, контейнером которого является.

Пример:

```
ISomeInterface
{
    void SomeMethodInterface(int someParam);
}
```

```
public SomeClass
{
    private ISomeInterface _instance;
}
```

Теперь если обратиться к классу `SomeClass`, я хочу получить методы интерфейса `ISomeInterface`, при этом отдавать ссылку на `ISomeIntarface` нельзя.

Важно понимать тот факт, что ни один класс не должен наследоваться от интерфейса.

Comment: Я ничего не понял

Comment: Ну что то на подобии перегрузки оператора `->` в `c++`.

Comment: Тоже ничего не понял.

Comment: Единственное, что мне в голову приходит, что гипотетически может подпасть под описание, это библиотека **moq**. Можно создавать заглушки для интерфейсов, для каждого метода будет своя реализация по умолчанию, которая ничего не делает. Часть реализаций можно переопределить.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko Ну, или прокси объект в DI-контейнере (декоратор)

Comment: Может пример приведете? Покажите как Вы хотите работать с этим классом/интерфейсом.

Comment: @LLENN может ты хотел заново изобрести DI-container? ты же знаешь что это?

Answer (score 0):

> Что я имел ввиду в заголовке, так это то, что бы к примеру абстрактный класс, мог стать контейнером некого интерфейса, и что бы при обращении к этому классу, я имел доступ ко всем методам интерфейса, но так что бы мне не приходилось их реализовывать вручную.

Вот это не вкурил вообще что нужно.

Но если читать только сам заголовок....

> Как определить класс с интерфейсом так, что бы он имел методы интерфейса, но без их реализации

Сделать класс абстрактным и метод с интерфейса абстрактным:

```
interface ITest
{
    void TestMethod(int a, int b);
}


abstract class TestAbstract : ITest
{
    public abstract void TestMethod(int a, int b);
}
```

Все что ты просил солюдено: 
есть метод, нет имплементации тела.

но не уверен это ли ты вообще хотел...

---

Так же стоит добавить то, что в C#8 появится возможность писать интерфейсы с реализацией:

```
interface IDisplayService
{
    void DisplayMessage(string message) 
    {
        WriteLine(message); 
    }
}
```

т.е. если использовать восьмерку, то что реализацию что ее отсутствие можно будет сделать в рамках одного лишь интерфейса.

Comment: `что бы мне не приходилось их реализовывать вручную` автору походу нужен декоратор, но он не хочет все методы реализовывать в абстрактном классе

Comment: @tym32167, не говорит ли это о слишком большой зоне ответственности класса?

Comment: @АндрейNOP быть декоратором?

Comment: @tym32167, я имею ввиду, если какая-то (значительная) часть методов не нужны в некотором из сценариев, не значит ли это, что у класса слишком много ответственности?

Comment: @АндрейNOP `что бы к примеру абстрактный класс, мог стать контейнером некого интерфейса` абстрактный класс на то и абстрактный, что часть методов именно в нем не надо реализовывать.

Comment: Хм, или имеется ввиду, что нам нужно декорировать малую часть методов, а остальные все пробросить агрегированному объекту? Ну все равно тогда ведь эту часть можно вынести в отдельный класс, %)

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать методы расширения для интерфейсов.

```
interface IFoo
{
}

class Foo : IFoo
{
}

static class Extension
{
    static public int DoWork(this IFoo foo, int n)
    {
        return n * 2;
    }
}
```

Используем:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var result = foo.DoWork(5);
Console.WriteLine(result); // 10
```

Подходит?

Comment: Увы, но нет, приходится описывать метод. Но, у интерфейса который  я получаю уже все есть, нужно просто поместить его в контейнер, через который можно получить методы интерфейса, не прибегая к вызову геттеров или полей класса. Отдавать чистый интерфейс опасно.

Answer (score 0):

Это невозможно в общем случае.

Ну и непонятно, почему вы не хотите написать просто явно:

```
public SomeClass
{
    private ISomeInterface _instance;

    public void SomeMethodInterface(int someParam)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

?